# Relative singular chains basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, free-groups

If $(X,A)$ is a pair, then $S_k(X,A):=S_k(X)/S_k(A)$ is free on the singular simplicies of $X$ with image not contained in $A$. Why is this so? I tried to give a proof by checking the mapping property of the free abelian group generated by these simplicies, but failed somehow. Is this result a special case of a more general (probably algebraic) proposition?

Comment: I don't see any need for propositions. Try to look at an element of $S_k(X,A)$ a convince yourself that it is precisely what you get by setting the coefficient to 0 for every element which is in $S_k(A)$.

Comment: @M.B. I want a proof

Comment: please, what you are trying to prove is obvious. Therefore it is important that you convince yourself of that, rather than trying to apply some (fancy) algebraic tools. What Stefan does in his answer is very close to the very definition of a free group. And on another note you should tone down your voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $S$ is a set which is a disjoint  union $B\sqcup A$, then the free Abelian group on $S$ is the direct sum of the free Abelian groups on $B$ and on $A$.
$$F(S)=F(B)\oplus F(A)$$
It follows that $F(B)=F(S)/F(A)$

In your case $S$ is the set of all simplices in $X$, $A$ is the set of simplices in $A$, and $B$ the set of simplices whose image is not in $A$.

Comment: very cool proof

Comment: so in this case a quotient of free groups if free, but this isnt always the case?

Comment: A free abelian group $H$ which is a subgroups of a free abelian group $G$ may or may not give a free abelian quotient. For example $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\Bbb Z_2$.